# How To fetch close event of default browser using VC++/C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

First I open web browser using **`shellexecute`** command.
then How we can get close event of browser using MFC/VC++/C++?

Comment: monitor browser process is ok? or WaitForSingleObject()

Answer (score 0):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> To obtain information about the application that is launched as a
>   result of calling ShellExecute, use ShellExecuteEx.

And a quick lookup on stackoverflow gives [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638674/how-to-wait-for-shellexecute-to-run), whose answer I quote here:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpFile = "c:\\MyProgram.exe";        
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = "";   
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL; 
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
```