# How to wait for ShellExecute to run multiple files?

Tags: visual-c++, waitformultipleobjects, shellexecuteex

I already found the code to make the programm wait for ShellExecuteEx in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638674/how-to-wait-for-shellexecute-to-run).
How can i make ShellExecuteEx start multiple files and wait until every file is closed?

Here is the code to wait for one:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpFile = "c:\\MyProgram.exe";        
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = "";   
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL; 
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
```

Comment: Call `ShellExecuteEx` multiple times, once per file you want to start, then wait on all handles (either at once with `WaitForMultipleObjects`, or one by one).

Comment: I got this for the waitingpart :

    `WaitForMultipleObjects(4, hProcess, TRUE, INFINITE)`

But how can I assign different HANDELS to each execution of the file ?

Comment: That wouldn't compile. The second parameter of `WaitForMultipleObjects` is not `HANDLE` but `HANDLE*` - a pointer to an array of `N` handles, where `N` is the first parameter. Anyway, to make things simple, you can just call `WaitForSingleObject` in a loop, once for each handle.