# ShellExecute returning success but file is not created

Tags: c, windows, msdn

Iam using ShellExecute WIN API to run DOS command because DOS command flashes are seen when i run the application. Below is the ShellExecute API call.

ret = ShellExecute(0, "open", "cmd.exe", "/C ver > version.txt", 0, SW_HIDE);

After this I tried to open version.txt using fopen function but it is returning NULL.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ShellExecute()` runs the specified process asynchronously. The reason `fopen()` is failing is almost certainly that the `cmd` process has not had enough time to actually create the file.

There are a couple of ways to solve this. Probably the best one for your case is to instead use `ShellExecuteEx()` to retrieve the process handle in `hProcess`, which will allow you to wait for its termination before resuming your code. See [How to wait for ShellExecute to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638674/how-to-wait-for-shellexecute-to-run).